# Creating element to add to DOM tree resulting in undefined?

Tags: javascript

Hello Stack Overflow,

I am having difficulties refactoring my code. It turns out when I create an element in another function `createEmailPreview` and add the node `unreadNotification`, it results in `undefined`, however when all the `unreadNotification` logic was inside my `createEmailPreview` everything worked fine.

Here's my error:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: unreadNotification is not defined
    at createEmailPreview (inbox.js:162)
    at inbox.js:115
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at showAllEmailPreviews (inbox.js:113)
    at inbox.js:100
```

Here's my javascript.

```js
function createNotification(type) {

  const notification = document.createElement("span")
  let badge = "badge badge-"

  if (type === "unread") {
    notification.className = badge + "warning"
    notification.innerHTML = "Unread"
  }
  else if (type === "archived"){
    notification.className =  badge + "info"
    notification.innerHTML = "Archived"
  }

  return notification
}


function createEmailPreview(emaildata , mailbox) {

  const email = document.createElement("li")
  email.addEventListener("click", event => displayEmail(event));
  const emailPreviewContent = document.createElement("h5")
  const userDidSend = (mailbox === "sent")

  
  let otherUsers = null;

  if (userDidSend){
    otherUsers = emaildata["recipients"];
    
  } 
  else {
    otherUsers = emaildata["sender"];

    unreadNotification = createNotification("unread");

    email.appendChild(unreadNotification)
    
  }


  email.id = emaildata["id"]
  email.className = "list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light";
  emailPreviewContent.innerHTML = `${otherUsers} - ${emaildata["subject"]} - ${emaildata["body"] } - ${emaildata["timestamp"] }` 
  emailPreviewContent.style.textOverflow = "ellipsis"
  email.appendChild(emailPreviewContent)

  return email;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your variables with `let` or `const` or `var`, but `unreadNotification` is not declared.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fresh eyes ... I'm an idiot for missing that lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your variable named `unreadNofitication` first with `const`, `let` or `var` like below:

```js
function createNotification(type) {

  const notification = document.createElement("span")
  let badge = "badge badge-"

  if (type === "unread") {
    notification.className = badge + "warning"
    notification.innerHTML = "Unread"
  }
  else if (type === "archived"){
    notification.className =  badge + "info"
    notification.innerHTML = "Archived"
  }

  return notification
}


function createEmailPreview(emaildata , mailbox) {

  const email = document.createElement("li")
  email.addEventListener("click", event => displayEmail(event));
  const emailPreviewContent = document.createElement("h5")
  const userDidSend = (mailbox === "sent")

  
  let otherUsers = null;

  if (userDidSend){
    otherUsers = emaildata["recipients"];
    
  } 
  else {
    otherUsers = emaildata["sender"];

    const unreadNotification = createNotification("unread");

    email.appendChild(unreadNotification)
    
  }


  email.id = emaildata["id"]
  email.className = "list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light";
  emailPreviewContent.innerHTML = `${otherUsers} - ${emaildata["subject"]} - ${emaildata["body"] } - ${emaildata["timestamp"] }` 
  emailPreviewContent.style.textOverflow = "ellipsis"
  email.appendChild(emailPreviewContent)

  return email;
}
```

By the way, you don't have to set this value to a variable in your case. You can just pass as argument to `email.appendChild` like this:

```js
    email.appendChild(createNotification("unread"))
```